# column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone django/postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, date

There were a `date` charfield , when I saved date as string before. But now I changed the field from charfield to datetimefield and dropped all previous data.

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Localy it works fine, but in production it raises following error when trying to migrate . I dropped the column , the model, commented and uncommented, deleted and created the field again, returned to previous migrations and migrated again, but all that didn't help.

```
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING date::timestamp with time zone".
```

How to solve the problem correctly? Using django 1.8, python 2.7 and postgres

Answer (score 6):

To anyone finding this question on Google when trying to convert an integer column to a timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN my_column
TYPE timestamp with time zone
USING to_timestamp(my_column);
```

Answer (score 3):

If your column is not fully convertable from the original type from the new one, consider to drop the old column and create a new one:

- comment out the column field in the model
- makemigration (will be generated a delete migration for this field) -> **YOU WILL DROP ALL COLUMN DATA**
- migrate Leave the comment in the model run again makemigration (now will be generated a new migration with the new column with the new
  datatype)
- run again migrate to apply the changes

This works well if you have few fields, but if you have many fields to convert i recommend to write a specific datamigration for that

Answer (score 2):

Run this in postgres shell :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE timestamp with time zone USING col_name::timestamp with time zone
```

Comment: is there any non interrupting database solution? could it cause any problems ?

Comment: If your column is fully convertable to date and has not any invalid data no problems will occur