# While altering column with type time to timestamp using FluentMigrator I faced error

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I want to alter a column with type time to timestamp using FluentMigrator
here is my code

```
this.Alter.Table(Tables.Events.Name)
    .InSchema(Tables.DefaultSchemaName)
    .AlterColumn(Tables.Events.ColumnsCreatedTime.Name).AsDateTime();
```

but it is giving me an error The error was "42804: column "CreatedTime" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp without time zone".

Comment: additional info the column createdtime has existing values type time i think that is what preventing it to be alter is there a way to update the existing rows while altering the column using fluentmigrator

Comment: @Jonathan- you're not wrong.  Q: Did any of the links/suggested alternatives in my response help?  Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you so much but im trying to solve the issue using FluentMigrator but im afraid i have to use RawSql in this case

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a new DateTime With CreatedTime

```
new DateTime(CreatedTime);
```

Comment: im trying to alter a column i think the problem is the column has existing values that can't be converted to timestamp and i have to use fluentmigrator

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the problem - and the solution:

> [column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone django/postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965016/)
>
> **Error:**
> `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "date" cannot be cast automatically to type timestamp with time zone HINT:  You might need to specify "USING date::timestamp with time zone".`
>
> **Solution:** If your column is not fully convertable from the original type from the new one, consider to drop the old column and
> create a new one:
>
> - comment out the column field in the model
> - makemigration (will be generated a delete migration for this field) -> YOU WILL DROP ALL COLUMN DATA
> - migrate Leave the comment in the model
> - run again makemigration (now will be generated a new migration with the new column with the new datatype)
> - run again migrate to apply the changes This works well if you have few fields, but if you have many fields to convert I recommend to
>   write a specific datamigration for that

Here's another possible solution (same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965016)):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name TYPE timestamp with time zone USING col_name::timestamp with time zone
```

There are differences between your environment and the other thread (for example, you're using C#, the other thread was using Python) - but I believe it's the same underlying issue.

Q: What is your database? PostgreSQL, or "Something else"?